# How can I create a mutable array in one class that I can access in a different class?

Tags: objective-c

In Stephen Kochan’s Programming in Objective-C 6th edition, he says you can create a pointer to an array, but I am getting Xcode errors. My desire is to create a mutable array in one class but be able to access it in a different class. Here is my simplified code where I create the array then try to get set the pointer to it and then return the value:

```
-(NSUInteger) makeArray {
    NSArray *members = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Keith", nil];
    NSUInteger *membersPtr;
    membersPtr = members;
    return *monthNamesPtr;
}
```

I’m getting two errors in the 3rd line (`membersPtr = members;` - this is right from the book so I think the rules have changed since the book was written).  The errors are:

> Implicit  conversion of an Objective-C  pointer to ‘NSUInteger ’ (aka ‘unsigned long *’) is disallowed with ARC
>
> Incompatible pointer types assigning to ‘NSUInteger *’ (aka unsigned long *’) from NSArray *_strong’

Comment: NSArray *members = @[@"Keith"];

Comment: Your integer conversion doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed. It should read: return *membersPtr;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are coming from `C` background and thats why you are trying to simulate something of sort `int *ptr` here by taking NSUInteger. Let me explain briefly:

```
NSArray *members = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Keith", nil];
```

Here `member` is a pointer to the NSArray object (Objective-C collection type) that contains "Keith" as first collection item. Now if you need to return the pointer to this array, simply change the method to:

```
-(NSArray *) makeArray {
    NSArray *members = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Keith", nil];
    return *members;
}
```

Comment: I had to make 1 small change to this "return members;" and then it worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want do this,it will make no error

```
-(NSUInteger) makeArray {
    NSArray *members = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Keith", nil];
    NSUInteger *membersPtr;
    membersPtr = (NSUInteger)members;
    return *membersPtr;
}
```

And I think **Singleton** is a better way!
U Can create class and add this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your 1st set of code still face me errors and I don't understand the 2nd set of code. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: OK! I run my 1st code.only got a warning but run it well!=.=in xcode 6.4 and 10.10.5 Mac=.=